# Will iphone application be allowed to parse url's from other servers?

Tags: iphone, webserver

In my application, I am using our own server for posting xml's and to parse them. My doubt is does apple allow to use it OR will they demand to take some space in the apple server and then to do all the things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can load your own file in your application !

See [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) of iOS Reference Library

Comment: So its like how I test right now. The application from appstore will also do the same with the external server, no need for apple space and all?